# Web Crawler Page Request only retrieves Redirect

Tags: php

I'm using PHP to retrieve some Salesforce content, but when I do a request, Salesforce only return redirect information (such as: `window.location.replace('link_here')`. Is there a reason for that? Is there anyway around it using web scraping? I simply need the actual page content.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two things probably going on (and you need to consider every time you create a web scraper):

1. You need to spoof your user agent.  [Find your browser's user-agent string here](http://www.useragentstring.com/) (for an example of what to set your user-agent to), and [here's one way to spoof your user agent with a php request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8974789/691835).
2. You may be getting redirected if javascript is not supported, unfortunately there's not a whole lot you can do about this.  I don't suspect this is the case, however, because they wouldn't be giving you a javascript command (from your example window.location.replace('link_here')) in this case.